# Find duplicated rows (based on 2 columns) in Data Frame in R

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which looks like:

```
| RIC    | Date                | Open   |
|--------|---------------------|--------|
| S1A.PA | 2011-06-30 20:00:00 | 23.7   |
| ABC.PA | 2011-07-03 20:00:00 | 24.31  |
| EFG.PA | 2011-07-04 20:00:00 | 24.495 |
| S1A.PA | 2011-07-05 20:00:00 | 24.23  |
```

I want to know if there's any duplicates regarding to the combination of RIC and Date. Is there a function for that in R?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can always try simply passing those first two columns to the function `duplicated`:

```
duplicated(dat[,1:2])
```

assuming your data frame is called `dat`. For more information, we can consult the help files for the `duplicated` function by typing `?duplicated` at the console. This will provide the following sentences:

> Determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of
>   elements with smaller subscripts, and returns a logical vector
>   indicating which elements (rows) are duplicates.

So `duplicated` returns a logical vector, which we can then use to extract a subset of `dat`:

```
ind <- duplicated(dat[,1:2])
dat[ind,]
```

or you can skip the separate assignment step and simply use:

```
dat[duplicated(dat[,1:2]),]
```

Comment: How can I retrieve the duplicated rows? I don't know how the results of duplicated function is indexed.

Comment: @user802231 - Edited to address your further query.

Comment: I tried, but the result seems not correct. What I get is showed below: (number in front of each line is row name)

          RIC                Date
107515 7541.T 2011-06-30 20:00:00
107516 7541.T 2011-07-03 20:00:00
107517 7541.T 2011-07-04 20:00:00
107518 7541.T 2011-07-05 20:00:00
107519 7541.T 2011-07-06 20:00:00
107520 7541.T 2011-07-07 20:00:00
107521 7541.T 2011-07-10 20:00:00
107522 7541.T 2011-07-11 20:00:00
107523 7541.T 2011-07-12 20:00:00
107524 7541.T 2011-07-13 20:00:00
107525 7541.T 2011-07-14 20:00:00
107526 7541.T 2011-07-18 20:00:00

Comment: @user802231 What's the problem?

Comment: Watch out with this solution!! It will only return `TRUE` for exactly the same *combination* of columns 1 and 2, not if the digits are inversed. In other words: `A,B` (that is, if these are the values of column 1 and column 2, respectively) will be flagged as duplicate if there's another `A,B`, but *not* if there's a `B,A`

Answer (score 30):

dplyr is so much nicer for this sort of thing:

```
library(dplyr)
yourDataFrame %>%
    distinct(RIC, Date, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

(the ".keep_all is optional. if not used, it will return only the deduped 2 columns. when used, it returns the deduped whole data frame)

Comment: How would you do it if you just want to know whether duplicate values exist?

Comment: While this is a useful trick in general, it doesn't answer the question the OP posted, which is how one identifies duplicate observations.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a `dplyr` option for tagging duplicates based on two (or more) columns. In this case `ric` and `date`:

```
df <- data_frame(ric = c('S1A.PA', 'ABC.PA', 'EFG.PA', 'S1A.PA', 'ABC.PA', 'EFG.PA'),
                 date = c('2011-06-30 20:00:00', '2011-07-03 20:00:00', '2011-07-04 20:00:00', '2011-07-05 20:00:00', '2011-07-03 20:00:00', '2011-07-04 20:00:00'),
                 open = c(23.7, 24.31, 24.495, 24.23, 24.31, 24.495))

df %>% 
  group_by(ric, date) %>% 
  mutate(dupe = n()>1)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ric, date [4]
  ric    date                 open dupe 
  <chr>  <chr>               <dbl> <lgl>
1 S1A.PA 2011-06-30 20:00:00  23.7 FALSE
2 ABC.PA 2011-07-03 20:00:00  24.3 TRUE 
3 EFG.PA 2011-07-04 20:00:00  24.5 TRUE 
4 S1A.PA 2011-07-05 20:00:00  24.2 FALSE
5 ABC.PA 2011-07-03 20:00:00  24.3 TRUE 
6 EFG.PA 2011-07-04 20:00:00  24.5 TRUE
```

Answer (score 10):

Easy way to get the information you want is to use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

yourDF %>% 
  group_by(RIC, Date) %>% 
  mutate(num_dups = n(), 
         dup_id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(is_duplicated = dup_id > 1)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  RIC    Date                 open num_dups dup_id is_duplicated
  <chr>  <chr>               <dbl>    <int>  <int> <lgl>        
1 S1A.PA 2011-06-30 20:00:00  23.7        1      1 FALSE        
2 ABC.PA 2011-07-03 20:00:00  24.3        2      1 FALSE        
3 EFG.PA 2011-07-04 20:00:00  24.5        2      1 FALSE        
4 S1A.PA 2011-07-05 20:00:00  24.2        1      1 FALSE        
5 ABC.PA 2011-07-03 20:00:00  24.3        2      2 TRUE         
6 EFG.PA 2011-07-04 20:00:00  24.5        2      2 TRUE
```

Using this:

- `num_dups` tells you how many times that particular combo is duplicated
- `dup_id` tells you which duplicate number that particular row is (e.g. 1st, 2nd, or 3rd, etc)
- `is_duplicated` gives you an easy condition you can filter on later to remove all the duplicate rows (e.g. `filter(!is_duplicated)`), though you could also use `dup_id` for this (e.g. `filter(dup_id == 1)`)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove duplicate records based on values of Columns **Date** and **State** in **dataset** data.frame:

```
#Indexes of the duplicate rows that will be removed: 
duplicate_indexes <- which(duplicated(dataset[c('Date', 'State')]),) 
duplicate_indexes 

#new_uniq will contain unique dataset without the duplicates. 
new_uniq <- dataset[!duplicated(dataset[c('Date', 'State')]),] 
View(new_uniq)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a way to return a data frame of the duplicated rows in the same format as your original data. There is probably a more elegant way to do this but this works:

```
dup <- data.frame(as.numeric(duplicated(df$var))) #creates df with binary var for duplicated rows
colnames(dup) <- c("dup") #renames column for simplicity
df2 <- cbind(df, dup) #bind to original df
df3 <- subset(df2, dup == 1) #subsets df using binary var for duplicated`
```

Answer (score 1):

Found quite a masterful idea [posted by Steve Lianouglou](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/71837/#71839) that helps solve this problem with the great advantage of indexing the repetitions:

If you generate a `hash` column concatenating both your columns for which you want to check duplicates, you can then use `dplyr::n()` together with `seq` to give an index to each duplicate occurrence as follows

```
dat %>% mutate(hash = str_c(RIC, Date)) %>%
  group_by(hash) %>% 
  mutate(duplication_id = seq(n()) %>%
 ungroup ()
```

Your column `duplication_id` tells you how many identical rows (same row values for both columns) are there in your table above the one indexed. I used this to remove duplicate Ids.