# Find out if column in R table includes duplicate values?

Tags: r, duplicates

I've got a lovely dataframe, my very first, and I'm starting to get the hang of R. One thing I haven't been able to find is a test for duplicate values. I have one column that I'm pretty sure is all unique values, but I don't know that.

Is there a way I can ask? For simplicity, let's pretend this is my data:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    A    1
2    2    B    3
3    3    C   NA
4    4    D   NA
5    5    E    4
```

and I want to know whether `var1` ever repeats.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the `duplicated` function:

```
duplicated(dat$var1) # the rows of dat var1 duplicated
```

Documentation is [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html).

You should also look at the `unique` function.

Comment: The documentation also mentions `anyDuplicated` which might be more directly relevant.

Comment: @Joran it should be pointed out that `any(duplicated(dat$var1))` will give a T/F value, where as `anyDuplicated(dat$var1)` will give an index/0 value.

Comment: anyDuplicated it is. So now it turns out that `anyDuplicated(j)` returns 2039, which is exactly what `anyDuplicated(j$should_be_unique)` returns. This is out of 81,000 records. I can produce a matrix object of TRUE/FALSE but can't examine that to see what some of those 2039 are. New question?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think I found the answer to that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986657/find-duplicated-column-pairs-in-data-frame-in-r?rq=1

Comment: incidentally, based on your other questions, this reference might be helpful: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf

Comment: Hah. that's on my desk right now but I buried it after it couldn't tell me about colClasses.

Comment: Note that `anyDuplicated` returns the index of the first duplicate, not a count of duplicates. The whole point of using it instead of any(duplicated(...)) is that it's faster to return a positive as it will stop at the first.

Comment: For future searchers - I find that `table(dat$var1)` gives me the summary I intuitively want: how many duplicate values are there in this column. In other words, is this a problem, and if so, how big is it?

Comment: You can use `sum(duplicated(dat$var1))` to get a count of duplicates.

Comment: Instead of values, if you have dates, for instance in `as.Date` what changes in the code do you need to do to find duplicate dates?

Answer (score 3):

Remove duplicates based on columns:

```
my_data[!duplicated(my_data$Col_id), ]  # Where ! is a logical negation:
```