# Is there a more elegant way to find duplicated records?

Tags: r, duplicates

I've got 81,000 records in my test frame, and `duplicated` is showing me that 2039 are identical matches. One answer to [Find duplicated rows (based on 2 columns) in Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986657/find-duplicated-column-pairs-in-data-frame-in-r) suggests a method for creating a smaller frame of just the duplicate records. This works for me, too:

```
dup <- data.frame(as.numeric(duplicated(df$var))) #creates df with binary var for duplicated rows
colnames(dup) <- c("dup") #renames column for simplicity
df2 <- cbind(df, dup) #bind to original df
df3 <- subset(df2, dup == 1) #subsets df using binary var for duplicated`
```

But it seems, as the poster noted, inelegant. Is there a cleaner way to get the same result: a view of just those records that are duplicates?

In my case I'm working with scraped data and I need to figure out whether the duplicates exist in the original or were introduced by me scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated(df)` will give you a logical vector (all values consisting of either T/F), which you can then use as an index to your dataframe **rows**.

```
# indx will contain TRUE values wherever in df$var there is a duplicate
indx <- duplicated(df$var)
df[indx, ]  #note the comma
```

---

You can put it all together in one line

```
df[duplicated(df$var), ]  # again, the comma, to indicate we are selected rows
```

Comment: Thanks. Will test later tonight. Time for a break from my headfirst flounding dive into R.

Comment: I wound up with this: `dupes <- df[duplicated(df),c('last','first','external_id')]` and then  `dupes.unique <- unique(dupes)` -- as it turns out some of the duplicates appear 10 or 12 times. With that I can go back to my source and confirm that I didn't introduce the duplication.

Answer (score -1):

```
doops <- which(duplicated(df$var)==TRUE)
uniques <- df[-doops,]
duplicates <- df[doops,]
```

Is the logic I generally use when I am trying to remove the duplicate entrys from a data frame.

Comment: You can avoid the `which` call and use `!` instead of `-`

Comment: changing = to <- in this scenario doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I was really just changing the capitilized `Which` to `which`. The rest was to make the edit valid.

Comment: You should probably change `=` to `==` too.

Comment: That doesnt really make sense as `==` is for comparing vectors while `=` in most instances will do the same thing as `->`

Comment: You could also remove the redundant `== TRUE`

Comment: @antishatter Google's R Style Guide does prefer `<-` to `=` and as someone who is just getting my bearings here I may as well learn to do it "right" http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#assignment