# Isolate Duplicates Records within qualitative groups R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know if it is possible to isolate duplicate records based from a date value but within groups. So essentially, I want extract records where for a given Title, ID, and category where the date values are the same?

Example:

```
Title   Title_ID   Category     Date
Title1    2728     Category 1   2013-08-09
Title1    2728     Category 2   2013-10-18
Title1    2728     Category 3   2013-11-05
Title1    2728     Category 4   2013-11-05
```

Desired Output:

```
Title   Title_ID   Category     Date
Title1    2728     Category 3   2013-11-05
Title1    2728     Category 4   2013-11-05
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within R's nifty packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense with the input data, did you typo? Look at the `duplicated` function and google

Comment: The output is to extract those last 2 rows from the main data frame that will give me Cat 3 & 4 where the dates are the same while controlling for the Title and ID variable. I have a list of 800 titles like this and need to isolate every instance of similar dates with respect to the other qualitative fields. And have tried using the `duplicated` function but the output gives me only one instance. I need both within the group for further data manipulation, Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but your main description is confusing. There are lots of resources related to your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986657/find-duplicated-rows-based-on-2-columns-in-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Again, I do not want ANY duplicate values. I am only looking for duplicate dates for a given Title and ID. I have research ALL through stackoverflow for similar cases which I have already seen these related issues you mentioned hence why the `duplicated` function in the second question, did not accomplish my task. Again, with a list of 800 titles, I am only trying to find duplicate date values with respect to the Title & ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two links I sent you in the comments are used together for this solution.

The first link shows you how to get all duplicate indices, not just the first one, with the `fromLast` argument combined with a `|` operator. The second shows you how to check for duplication across multiple columns. So you check for rows that have all the same `Title`, `Title_ID`, and `Date` values.

The last line of code removes exact duplicates if there are any in your dataframe. Your example doesn't include any and I'm not totally clear from your description

```
ind <- duplicated(dt[,c('Title', 'Title_ID', 'Date')]) | duplicated(dt[,c('Title', 'Title_ID', 'Date')], fromLast = T)

dt2 <- dt[ind,]

dt2[!duplicated(dt2),]
```

Comment: A combo of the solutions you gave did the trick. To be honest, did not think to use both questions yesterday when I found them in stackoverflow. But thank you for help. Much obliged sir!